# Safari Speech Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I have set up the Speech Recognition (speech to text) 
http://yjwebsoft.com/voice/

for some reason it works on chrome but not safari. But on the tutorial it meantioned that it does support Safari

Answer (score 1):

Speech recognition is chrome-only feature, it does not support Safari. You can find recent state here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition

Recently Firefox added support for speech recognition, but this feature is highly experimental, see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Comment: What is the case now?