# Client-side Speech Recognition on a mobile browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, speech-recognition, mobile-browser, mobile-chrome

I am working on a project that is targeted for browsers on smart phones. And I can't seem to find any way to do a client-side speech recognition, as the mobile version of chrome doesn't even support their own Web Speech API. Does anybody know how to have speech recognition working on a mobile browser like Chrome or Firefox? Or is there a work around that can be used? like a 3rd-party service that provide APIs to be called.

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#search=speech%20recognition it should work in Chrome on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Potential duplicate: [Safari Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883967/safari-speech-recognition)

**NOPE:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition

**NOPE:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

---

Not client side but might be of some assistance: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

Also this: https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy (seems like need to set up your RasPi)

And this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs I can totally imagine doing all the machine learning in the browser, just like you can run [Windows 95](https://win95.ajf.me/) and what not.